# How to set up flat rate shipping

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, table-rates

From what I've seen on the web Magento 2 should have an option for flat rate shipping in

```
stores -> config -> sales -> shipping methods
```

My install doesn't have anything to do with flat rate shipping. There are two shipping methods available: FedEx and UPS.  In the Component Manager both are enabled. I'm using Magento 2.0.4

I can't find any component in the Component Manager that looks like it might have anything to do with flat rate shipping.

My client only has one shipping method, a flat rate of £15 per order. And that's what I want to set up.

Is there something wrong with my setup? Otherwise, can someone tell me how to set up the flat rate?

Comment: You also mis default shippings methods like Cash on Delivery and such?

Comment: No I don't have cash on delivery. Shipping Methods contains ONLY Fedex and UPS, which I enabled in the Component Manager. Until I enabled those two, the shipping methods screen was empty.

Comment: If it makes any difference, I did not install the sample data when I installed magento as I didn't want to start off with lots of spurious data.

Answer (score 0):

The shipping is ONLY available for products that have weight set to Yes.

Configure it in your product details.

[image]